# Loading api using a store in svelte pulls the data only when toggling using nav links

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3, svelte-component, svelte-store

Using a store to fetch the an api the data does not load upon page reload. However by visiting the About page then by clicking the Home Nav link it does load the objects once then it seems to not allow to be modified.

```js
import {nfl} from "../stores/nflstore";
 
console.log($nfl);
```

In the store

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const nfl = writable([]);

const fetchNfl = async () => {
    const url = `https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/nfl/odds/json/LiveGameOddsByWeek/2020/2?key=`;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data = await res.json();
    
    const loadedData = data.map((data, index) => {
        return {
            isSelected: false,
            isSelectedAsParly: false,
            isSelectedAsTease: false,
            valueHomeSpread: false,
            valueAwaySpread: false,
            valueOverUnder: false,
            id: index + 1,
            away: data.AwayTeamName,
            away_spread: data.LiveOdds[0].AwayPointSpread,
            home: data.HomeTeamName,
            home_spread: data.LiveOdds[0].HomePointSpread,
            away_money_line: data.LiveOdds[0].AwayMoneyLine,
            home_money_line: data.LiveOdds[0].HomeMoneyLine,
            over_under: data.LiveOdds[0].OverUnder,
        };
        
    });
    nfl.set(loadedData);
};
fetchNfl();
```

Comment: Please do *not* screenshot code. Add in the question as text, there is a button for formatting as code. Also, please explain your question more clearly: What should happen; what is happening instead; steps to demonstrate the issue. Ideally create a minimal reproducing example that can be run in the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/) (the code should still be *in the question*).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, code in a module is only run once. So the fetch will happen once when the store code is loaded and the store value will not change until a hard page reload happens (possibly that is what you are referring to with "nav links").

What to do about this depends on the specifics of the application. E.g. you could export `fetchNfl` and call that in various places to fetch new data. The question then is whether the store is even required at all.

If you want to pass state between components it might be better to use `setContext`/`getContext` or just plain component properties. (You can also put the store in a context/property if necessary.)

Comment: Understanding how the objects are loaded was my problem I think my answer is to create another {#each} block to count the amount of items that  "isSelected"  to dynamically update the UI as the user adds to the list. Thank you for your help it confirmed to me not to be so concerned with the "console.log debugging" that I had been going around in circles to figure out.